# How can I make a TNT arrow in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

If I put this command in a command block:

```
execute at @e[type=arrow] ~ ~ ~ summon tnt ~ ~ ~
```

it says

> "Syntax error: unexpected "~":at "pe=arrow >>~<< ~ ~ summo"

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing new Java syntax with old Bedrock one, try:

```
execute @e[type=arrow] ~ ~ ~ summon tnt ~ ~ ~
```

or

```
execute as @e[type=arrow] at @s summon tnt ~ ~ ~
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the 2 is there so the arrow doesn't shoot the tnt then disappear

execute as @e[type=arrow] at @e[type=arrow] run summon tnt ~ ~2 ~